# URL Rewrite on the basis of two parameters

Tags: url-rewriting

i am new to URL Rewrite. i want to rewrite my URL like given below.

www.mywebsite.com/q/1st-parameter/2nd-parameter

to

www.mywebsite/1st-parameter/index.php?q=2nd-parameter

Please note that the 1st-parameter/2nd-parameter is a string and it also contain "-". the Rule which i used in .htaccess file is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^.+/q/([a-z,A-Z,0-9]+)/([a-z,A-Z,0-9]+)   /$1/index.php?q=$2    [NC,L,R]
```

Your quick reply will be highly appreciated. kindly also look at the Flags, whether i am using the correct flags or not. infact i copied it from a forum but failed to get the correct results.
Thanks in Advance